# why authenctication Header is not sent when apple tests application?

Tags: ios, voip, registration, pjsip

we have iOS application for VoIP call. When I register user in our application there is no problem means Authentication header is added and everything works fine. I submitted application on Appstore.When they registered and tested application Authentication header is not added in register message.Why this happens.Is there any specific reason?If not how can I fix this.Any hint will be helpful for me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think so Apple does have any connection with removing Authentication header info from **SIP** message.

Might be in code level you have added authentication header inside debug mode so when you are running application yourself you can see that header information is available.

**What you can do now?** 
You can create adhoc build and upload on diawi or test flight and download that build in your phone and test are you facing same issue or not.